# How to wait for Angular module to load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, i18next

I'm trying to use i18next (https://github.com/archer96/ng-i18next) in my Angular project, but it seems to be loading too slow. This is my setup:

```
angular.module('jm.i18next').config(['$i18nextProvider', function ($i18nextProvider) {
    $i18nextProvider.options = {
        lng: 'en',
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        preload: ['en'],
        supportedLngs: ['en'],
        resGetPath: '../locales/__lng__.json',
        useCookie: false,
        useLocalStorage: false,
        defaultLoadingValue: ''
    };
}]);

angular.module('myApp', ['jm.i18next']).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$i18next', function ($scope, $i18next) {
console.log($i18next("key"));

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($i18next("key"));
  }, 1000);
}]);
```

I have to add a timeout to have a value. Is there a way to make sure i18next is ready when the controller is loaded?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to group workouts by type, which is translated using $i18next. But this doesnt work, since the view is "ready" before the controller has done the translation.

```
<select ng-model="workout" ng-options="workout as workout.name group by workout.type for workout in workouts | orderBy: ['type', 'name']"></select>

$scope.workouts = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Workout 1', type: $i18next("type1")},
    {id: 25, name: 'Workout 2', type: $i18next("type2")},
  ];
```

Comment: hey, isn't your controller linked to a view? If so you could use a resolve on the route to wait until the module is loaded. But usually angular would wait until all modules are loaded before running... Is there an ajax request in that module?

Comment: Its linked to a view, which includes a select box. The problem is that the ng-options includes a list of i18next texts, and the view seems to be "ready" before the controller. If that makes sense :)

I'll update my original post.

Comment: so in the route, add a resolve: { i18next: function(YourModule){return YourModulePromise}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'jm.i18next']).
        config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/route1', {
                    title: 'Route 1',
                    templateUrl: '../views/route1.html',
                    controller: 'Route1Ctrl',
                    resolve: {
                      i18next: function ($i18next) {
                        return $i18next;
                      }
                    }
                });
    }]);
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed it. Although IMO this is an ugly solution because you have to put this resolve function on every route...

Answer (score 0):

You could also listen to the `i18nextLanguageChange` event:

```
$scope.$on('i18nextLanguageChange', function () {
  $scope.workouts = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Workout 1', type: $i18next("type1")},
    {id: 25, name: 'Workout 2', type: $i18next("type2")},
  ];
});
```

You'll have to tackle other race conditions on your own that way.